# update not working using ajax call in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, methods

I am trying to update my 'section' item list but it's updating only first one and update not working for other items from the list and getting 'MethodNotAllowedException' except the first one. I did not find the reason. Would someone help me to find out the reason, please?

> index.blade.php

```
<td class="text-center">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal-{{ $section->id }}"> <i class="fa fa-pencil text-warning m-r-10"></i> </a>

  <!-- Edit Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="editModal-{{ $section->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel1">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
             <form id="editForm" method="POST">

                   @method('PUT')

                   @csrf

             <div class="modal-header text-left">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                   <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel1">Update Section</h4>
             </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                    <div id="updatesuccess-msg" class="hide text-left">
                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                     </button>
                        <strong>Success:</strong> Section Updated !
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-left">
                         <label for="section" class="control-label">Section Name:</label>
                         <input type="text" name="section" value="{{ $section->section }}" class="form-control" >
                         <input type="hidden" name="section_id" class="sec_id" value="{{ $section->id }}">
                         <span class="text-danger">
                              <small id="updateinput-error"></small>
                         </span>
                     </div>

                     </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                   </div>
           </form>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> Ajax

```
$("#editForm").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var form = $("#editForm");
var formData = form.serialize();
var sectionId = parseInt($('.sec_id').val());
       $( '#input-error' ).html( "" );

       $.ajax({
           url:'{{ url("admin/section") }}' + '/' + sectionId,
           method:'PUT',
           data:formData,
           success:function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if(data.errors) {
                   if(data.errors.section){
                       $( '#updateinput-error' ).html( data.errors.section[0] );
                   }

            }
            if(data.success) {
                $('#updatesuccess-msg').removeClass('hide');
                    setInterval(function(){ 
                       $('#editForm').modal('hide');
                       $('#updatesuccess-msg').addClass('hide');
                       location.reload();
             }, 1000);
        }
    },
});
```

});

> SectionController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
              'section' => 'required|max:255|unique:sections',
          ]);

          $sectionId = $request->input('section_id');
          if ($validator->passes()) {

             // Update your section in database
             $data = Section::find($sectionId);
             $data->section = $request->section;
             $data->save();

            return Response::json(['success' => '1']);
            //return response()->json($data);

          }

  return Response::json(['errors' => $validator->errors()]);
 }
```

> web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth:admin'], 'as' => 'admin.'], function () { 
     Route::resource('section', 'Admin\HR\SectionController'); 
});
```

Comment: Tried `$("#editForm").submit(function(event) {` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried.

Comment: var sectionId = parseInt($('.sec_id').val()); getting always 1 as it's value.

Comment: @RashedHasan have u fixed that???

Answer (score 0):

Change ajax method to `POST`

`method:'POST'`

Comment: First I tried using ajax method 'POST', it was not working and someone told me to change to 'PUT', so I tried both 'POST' and 'PUT'.But not working.

Comment: It must be POST method. `update()` method must be called with POST method and with PUT parameter in hidden `_method` field. There is something other problem.

Comment: Changed to 'POST' method. When submitting the other items except first one, then browser network showing it's not getting the 'id'. Probably, that's why I am getting 'MethodNotAllowed' exception.

Answer (score 0):

use axios instead..

```
//update
axios.patch(url, {}).... //PATCH

//create
axios.post(url, {}).... //POST | PUT -> axios.put(url, {})

//get
axios.get(url, {})....  //GET

//delete
axios.delete(url, {}).... //DELETE
```

For your problem.. try to change from PUT to PATCH

see this resource controller laravel.. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: I tried both PUT and PATCH. (when I changed 'editForm' id to 'editForm' form class, then It's hitting the route. But, now it's  getting the first one ID value 1 for each item in the list and not updating.

Comment: If I want to axios, then I have to use vuejs, is not?. I tried to use vuejs, but I am using one paid admin template which use bootstrap 4 and in it jquery version has 'jQuery v3.1.1' and my app.js has jquery 3.3.7 and i am getting lot of conflicts.